# jquery tabs and rails : switching causing events to pile up?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-tabs

I've got two tabs as follows

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>  
        <li ><%= link_to 'A', a_path %></li> 
        <li ><%= link_to 'B', b_path %></li>    
  </ul>   
</div>
```

'A' renders with a link as follows:
    <%= link_to new_foo_path(:format=>:js),:remote=>true %>

When I click that link, I can see in the server log that it gets called two, sometimes 3 times.

I've got no special click handlers set anywhere. My tabs are initialized as follows:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
 });
```

Worse yet, if I switch back and forth between tabs, there's an increase in the number of remote calls made each time I click that link.

If I take tabs out of the picture, the link works as expected.

I'm running Rails 3 with jquery-1.4.4.min and  jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min. I've tried other combinations/versions of jquery with no luck.
Any ideas anyone?

thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Looks like this isn't really a Rails issue, but something that has to do with the tabs plugin triggering a click event when switched. It's really hard to say from this what's causing the problem. Can you please 1) link to the tabs plugin source code and 2) put up an html demo of the code that's causing the problem? (try removing the rails link and instead triggering an `alert()` message on click)

Comment: I believe the jQuery tabs works with content that is already on the page. You setup your html with the classes and so forth similar to the examples on the jQuery ui website. Then apply the jQuery function as needed to your elements. I set this up for a 3 part form i did as UI Tabs, and that was how i did it. Not to say you can't use ajax to request the dynamic html. Just requires a bit more work to load the separate html and so forth correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I had this part:

```
$(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
 });
```

In my main application layout template. This was therefore getting called for the content in each of the tabs, which caused that above function to be called multiple times. Once I moved it to the right place, things worked as expected.

Thanks yuval and agmcleod for your input.